# The text starts with # symbol is not inserted into the datatable

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, ionic3, angular4-httpclient

I am inserting address by passing address parameter to Service.The Address field contains text **Building No 1,#1-98-91/1,Sai Nagar**.Now my problem is after data insertion in the mysql database table address column it is saving as **Building No 1** the text starts with # is not inserting into the datatable.
(I am inserting this data through service in mobile app)

Please help me how to resolve this.

Comment: Is your service treating the `#` as the start of a comment and ignoring everything after?

Comment: Yes.Test after # symbol is not inserting into the database through service.

Comment: Please update the question with the code from the service.